# Word order of a sentence

Tags: prepositions, clauses

I have the following idea.

> In/when reconstructing geometrically and topologically correct 3D building
>   models, to get the advantage of high level of automation, one can
>   choose point clouds.

I feel the word order of the sentence is not smooth and would be good if it be

> To get the advantage of high level of automation, in/when reconstructing
>   geometrically and topologically correct 3D building models,  one can
>   choose point clouds.

and also

> To get the advantage of high level of automation, one can choose point clouds, in reconstructing geometrically and topologically correct 3D building models.

**NOTE: not sure in or when is most relevant**

Now I am totally confused what would be the most formal way. can anyone comment me on this.
all comments are welcome.
thanks

Comment: I suggest removing the comma before *in*, in both sentences.

Comment: @Damkerng T. : Did not get you, in which sentence?

Comment: Also consider getting rid of *in*: *Reconstructing geometrically and topologically correct 3D building models, one can choose point clouds to get the advantage of high level of automation.*

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that it is useful.

Comment: I would say that "to get the advantage of" is less natural than "to take advantage of" or "to benefit from". Between that and the extraneous comma, I'd suggest: _"To take advantage of / To benefit from the high level of automation, one can choose point clouds in reconstructing geometrically and topologically correct 3D building models."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence can be phrased in any of the three orders, but with a few caveats. I find you can often get a better sense of this sort of thing by simplifying the sentence. So consider:

Short answer: your first choice is best; your second is acceptable but would work with different punctuation; your third is not idiomatic and would likely confuse a native speaker.

> When building models, to get the best results, choose point clouds.

This is a well-constructed and easily understood sentence. You could use "in" here, but "when" is more idiomatic to my ear.

To change the emphasis, you could instead say:

> To get the best results when building models, choose point clouds.

This is also a good, clear sentence, with a slightly different emphasis; it emphasizes the results, rather than the model building. I think that it is clearer without the first comma, but either way will work here. Either way, you need to use "when" and not "in."

Your last sentence is the equivalent of

> To get the best results, choose point clouds when building models.

This is again acceptable--but again you would have to use "when" and not "in."

The real problem with the sentence is not word order; it is word choice. "Get the advantage of" is technically correct and will convey your intended meaning, but "take advantage of" is much more idiomatic. It would be clearer to include a subject for the high level of automation. "One can" will sound stilted and formalistic in almost any sentence; eliminate it if at all possible. Here, it can simply be eliminated.

These simple changes give you:

> To take advantage of the software's high level of automation when reconstructing geometrically and topologically correct 3D building models, choose point clouds.

Or my preferred order, which you didn't consider:

> When reconstructing geometrically and topologically correct 3D building models, choose point clouds to take advantage of the software's high level of automation.